# SQL error: The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql query:

```
select contactID, items.name, orders.confirmed, deleted, dbo.polish_date(orders.crDATE), orders.orderID, IDtowar, IDspecial, IDstatus, IDtype, description 
from orders, items
LEFT JOIN contacts ON orders.orderID = IDorder 
where (orders.IDuser='38824' and orders.IDtowar=items.itemID) 
order by orders.crDATE
```

And I have this error every time:

> The multi-part identifier "orders.orderID" could not be bound.

Comment: Does the column `orderID` exist in `orders` table?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT contactID, items.name, orders.confirmed, deleted, dbo.polish_date(orders.crDATE), orders.orderID, IDtowar, IDspecial, IDstatus, IDtype, description 
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN contacts ON orders.orderID = IDorder 
LEFT JOIN items ON orders.IDtowar = items.itemID
WHERE orders.IDuser='38824'
ORDER By orders.crDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the Orders to Items on the matching field in both tables, and similarly join the Contacts to Orders (assuming that's where the link resides) on it's matching field.

```
 SELECT contactID, items.name, orders.confirmed, deleted,
        dbo.polish_date(orders.crDATE), orders.orderID,
        IDtowar, IDspecial, IDstatus, IDtype, description 
   FROM orders
        LEFT JOIN items ON items.orderID = orders.orderId
        LEFT JOIN contacts ON contacts.ContactId = orders.ContactId
  WHERE (orders.IDuser='38824' and orders.IDtowar=items.itemID) 
  ORDER BY orders.crDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you what helped me and I think it will work with yours as well. I removed the table I am joining from the From clause - worked like a charm. This is what I think yours would look like:

```
SELECT contactID, items.name, orders.confirmed, deleted, dbo.polish_date(orders.crDATE),      orders.orderID, IDtowar, IDspecial, IDstatus, IDtype, description 
FROM items -- Delete orders from clause
LEFT JOIN contacts ON orders.orderID = IDorder 
WHERE (orders.IDuser='38824' and orders.IDtowar=items.itemID) 
ORDER BY orders.crDATE
```